# Fail to use Stepzen admin key

Tags: graphql

I am using Stepzen for GraphQL queries. I signed up with my GitHub account, ran npm install -g stepzen, then stepzen login, then provided my account name and my admin key but getting this error:
`Error: We are unable to verify your account details. Could you please check them? (Error: An unexpected error occurred. FetchError: request to  https://bourne.stepzen.io/cli/admin/account failed, reason: Hostname/IP  does not match certificate's altnames: Host: bourne.stepzen.io. is not in  the cert's altnames: DNS:*.fortinet.com)`
I am SUPER sure I am copying my admin key correctly but it's still not working. Any ideas?
https://stepzen.com/docs/quick-start/install-and-setup

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if it will be helpful..

I pasted my admin key but by using ctrl+v but it didnt work.
only one star* was on the terminal.

I tried again by pressing the right button of my mouse and it pasted correctly.

it worked.